# Passing HTML Element Through A Function

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pass the HTML element through a function, because I do not want to use ID's, I want to create the function dynamically.

The focus doesn't make sense here but it does make sense in my code:

```js
function MyFunction(passedObject) {
  alert(passedObject.value);
  passedObject.focus()
}
```

```html
<input onclick="MyFunction(this)">
```

I do not want to use a solution that uses ID's like this:

```js
function MyFunction() {
  alert(document.getElementById("TheInput").value);
  document.getElementById("TheInput").focus()
}
```

```html
<input id="TheInput" onclick="MyFunction()">
```

Comment: Which element do you want to pass? Does it have a clear structured relationship to the input element?

Comment: I want to pass the input element like in my example. So that passedObject.value will be the text inside the input box

Comment: @Frank — I click on it, it alerts a blank string (which is the text inside the input), I type something, I click on it again, it alerts what I typed (also the text inside the input). I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Yes I know. I the answer below I commented about noticing that my code works

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```js
function MyFunction(element) {
  alert(element.value);
  element.focus()
}
```

```html
<input onclick="MyFunction(this)" value="Hello World">
```

Comment: Oh, that is exactly my first example bhaha. For some reason it wasn't working when I tried it

Comment: This is the same as OPs first example? value="Hello World" doesnt add anything and id="TheInput" is not needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically define the function in your html generation with something like this:

`<input onclick="function(element) { alert(element.value); element.focus() }(this)" value="Hello World">`

A key part is that the function is passing this after the function declaration. The function will not exist until the button is clicked. If it exists before the button is clicked it will overwrite the previous declaration. You can also remove the function name and execute it as an anonymous function if you are only trying to execute the function and don't need to interact with it outside the onclick.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the solution: You'll have to select the element anyway using ID, but only once.

```
var input = document.getElementById("TheInput");

function MyFunction(passedObject) {
  alert(passedObject.value);
  passedObject.focus()
}

var inputElem = document.getElementById("TheInput");
MyFunction(inputElem)
```